# How do I handle "Input string was not in a correct format." when editing GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a **GridView** connected to an **SqlDataSource**. Most of my columns are *integers* and works as intended but I want to handle the correct input from the user instead of having it crash when editing the **GridView**.

What would I need to do to validate correct input?

Comment: use your EditTemplate of GridView to bind the value to a TextBox with Numeric type

Comment: you can use asp.net validators

Comment: It won't let me use validators as there aren't any TextBox's inside the GridView.

Comment: You could insert the validators dynamically (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Required-BoundField-Validate-BoundField-TextBox-in-Edit-Mode-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx) or use TemplateFields and provide your own editors and validators in markup.